# How can I delete all objects over 24 hours old using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to remove all un-complete accounts in my app where the user signed up, created an account but didn't finish the verification process by uploading certain images...

I am running a cron job that performs this task every 24 hours...

**I want to remove all objects where imageUrlOne & imageUrlTwo == "" AND createdAt is older than 24 hours.**

My current code isn't working, any idea what I am doing wrong?

THANK YOU

```
const User = require("../models/user-model")

const removeInactiveAccounts = async () => {
  let twentyFourHours = miliseconds(24, 0, 0)
  //                     hours, min, seconds

  function miliseconds(hrs, min, sec) {
    return (hrs * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec) * 1000
  }

  let startDate = Date.now() // todays date
  let endDate = startDate - twentyFourHours // 24 hours ago from today

  try {
 
    await User.deleteMany({
      imageUrlOne: "",
      imageUrlTwo: "",
      createdAt: {
        $gte: startDate,
        $lte: endDate,
      },
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}

module.exports = removeInactiveAccounts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your signs a little mixed up.

You're saying greater than "right now", and less than 24 hours ago.

For simplicity, let's say "right now" is `86400`. That would make "24 hours ago" `0`.

So, you have: `createdAt >= 86400 && createdAt <= 0`.

Well, that is impossible. No number can be greater than 86,400 and less than 0 at the same time.

You don't need to include the start date at all in this case. Ditch it and just have createdAt less than endDate and you should be good.